# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/POIXMLTypeLoader

Tags: java, csv, apache-poi

I have an issue with poi with regards to a XLS to CSV conversion. When I run as Java application the method runs fine but as soon as i try and run it from the web app i get this issue : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/POIXMLTypeLoader.

This is the pom file poi versions:

```
        <poi.version>4.1.2</poi.version>
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>${poi.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>${poi.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/ooxml-schemas -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
            <version>${poi.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

This is the java code for the conversion:

```
public static List<StringBuffer> convertXLSX(InputStream inputFile) {
        // Get the workbook object for XLSX file
        List<StringBuffer> toReturn = new ArrayList<>();
        int count = 0;
        try {
            @SuppressWarnings("resource")
            XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputFile);
            for (int l = workbook.getNumberOfSheets() - 1; l >= 0; l--) {
                // For storing data into CSV files
                StringBuffer data = new StringBuffer();
                XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(count);
                Cell cell;
                Row row;
                // Iterate through each rows from first sheet
                Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
                while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
                    row = rowIterator.next();
                    // For each row, iterate through each columns
                    Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
                    int columnNumber = 1;
                    while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                        cell = cellIterator.next();
                        if (columnNumber > 1) {
                            data.append(",");
                        }

                        switch (cell.getCellType()) {
                        case BOOLEAN:
                            data.append(cell.getBooleanCellValue());
                            break;

                        case NUMERIC:
                            if (DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)) {
                                data.append(HAJConstants.sdf.format(DateUtil.getJavaDate(cell.getNumericCellValue())));
                            } else {
                                data.append(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                            }
                            break;

                        case STRING:
                            data.append(cell.getStringCellValue());
                            break;

                        case BLANK:
                            data.append("");
                            break;

                        default:
                            data.append(cell);
                        }
                        ++columnNumber;
                    }
                    data.append('\n');
                }
                toReturn.add(data);
                count++;
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return toReturn;
    }
```

these are my imports:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DateUtil;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

import haj.com.constants.HAJConstants;
```

Comment: Can you describe more on your webapp? What framework you use?

Comment: I use JSF2 with PrimeFaces

Comment: Where do you run the war file? Tomcat? With your maven config dependencies are copied into the war file. NoClassDefFoundError suggests non-resolvable duplicate dependencies.

Comment: I've changed the loading of XmlBeans resources in POI a while ago and similar issues have been posted - my guess is also a duplicated xmlbeans.jar (or xbean.jar). Before finding the culprit in the framework classloaders, I would try to specify [parent-last classloading](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/class-loader-howto.html) - of course this depends on your j2ee application server or microservice environment.